# maxLength issue in Grails

Tags: grails

I'm using `Grails 2.5.1` , in my domain constrains to make the max characters in this field `50` ,so i wrote:

```
fullName(nullable:false,maxLength:50)
```

but nothing affected in the `_form`

```
<g:textField name="fullName" required="" value="${employmentSeekerInstance?.fullName}"/>
```

as far as i know it suppose to add `maxLengnth=50` to the `<g:textField>` am i right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a `maxLength` constraint. The correct constraint is `maxSize` and it will then add the `maxlength` attribute to the generated text field. See [the relevant line](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-scaffolding/blob/aa2841911745ac6c6aa759b89e7703a9856b9e6b/src/templates/scaffolding/renderEditor.template#L80) in the scaffolding plugin.